Does WSO2 APK(API Platform for Kubernetes) have Graphical User Interface such as DevPortal and Publisher and Admin , ....?
We explore a way that has the last version of WSO2 APIM with Publisher and Devportal and Carbon and Admin , ... and at the same time have Scalable Gateway to execute for example 2000 requests per second. What is the best and easiest way for that?
I heard something about APK  but I think it does not have GUI. Am I right?
We use Docker Swarm but we have some problems such as Consistency and Gateway error. For solving that we used HazelCast but we have problem yet.
What is the best and easiest way for having scalable APIM with GUI and no problem in consistency and related problems?
Thank you for you Suggestion as an experienced in WSO2

You can use the distributed deployment of WSO2 API Manager for this purpose. The control plane profile with the GUIs can be used for management purposes while having the synapse gateway separately. The gateway can be scaled horizontally to your requirement. This can be easily done if you deploy this in Kubernetes (using HPA). You can refer the distributed deployment docs for more information [1].
APK [2] is a new Kubernetes native gateway introduced by WSO2 leveraging the capabilities of Envoy and Kubernetes Gateway API [3]. You can also use this as the gateway in your deployment instead of the default synapse gateway. The API Manager's Control Plane can be connected to APK Gateway and easily [4].
You can use either of those solutions based on your requirements. Both are capable of handling high TPS scenarios easily and can be scaled if required.
[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/understanding-the-distributed-deployment-of-wso2-api-m/
[2] - https://apk.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/about-apk/what-is-apk/
[3] - https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/
[4] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-apim-as-a-gateway/
